# Connect WebSphere Application Server datasource on Bluemix to on-premise database

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-was-oc

I've been looking for information on how a WebSphere Application Server datasource on Bluemix can connect to a database on-promise, but haven't found much.

I read that Secure Gateway can help connecting on-premise resources to other apps on Bluemix, but I still have questions about the connection information that you should configure on your datasource:

- What IP or hostname address should I give?
- Is it necessary to have a public IP in order to make the connection?

I want to run a simple test deploying DayTrader3 app on WAS on Bluemix and connect it to an on-premise DB2 to test the latency and response times, compared to a full on-premise solution. Any guidance on this configuration is really appreciated!

Comment: have a look at this article, which describes how to set up on-prem DB2 w/ Bluemix Secure Gateway, and also shows where to find the host/port to use in your JDBC credentials: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2015/11/05/access-an-on-premises-db2-data-server-from-the-bluemix-cloud/

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the article! I was able to successfully connect to my on premise DB2 following the configurations mentioned there!